# How to access data of a filter query in firestore flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, filtering

I want to search for the user from his mobile number. If the user found then show his other information like Name, Surname.

[image]

The search query is working fine. But I'm not able to access the data. Below is my function to get the result of the query. When I print the data its just prints *[Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot']*

```dart
  getData() async {
    final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('CommonData')
        .where(
          'Mobile_Number',
          isEqualTo: mobileNumber,
        )
        .get();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> resultDocument = result.docs;
    
    print(resultDocument);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
getData() async {
  String mobile_number;
  String name;
  String surname;

  final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('CommonData')
      .where(
        'Mobile_Number',
        isEqualTo: mobileNumber,
      )
      .get();
  result.docs.forEach((value) {
    mobile_number = value.data()['Mobile_Number'];
    name = value.data()['Name'];
    surname = value.data()['SurName'];
  });

  print("Mobile Number: " + mobile_number);
  print("Name: " + mobile_number);
  print("SurName: " + mobile_number);
}
```

Comment: Ya, after applying your solution the data is printed in the Map.  But I want to store the individual value in the variable. Can you help with that?

Comment: @JayTillu i updated my example answer. You can also create a class model for your user profile too.

Comment: hi after using ur getData function, can I use  StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("example").snapshots(), to display filtered data in list/card view?

Answer (score 1):

Since you make the assumption that your DB does contain one and only one User per Mobile Number, you might want to enforce this assumption:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getData(String mobileNumber) async {
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('CommonData')
      .where(
        'Mobile_Number',
        isEqualTo: mobileNumber,
      )
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => snapshot.docs.single.data())
      .catchError(
    (e) {
      if (e.message == 'No element') {
        print("Couldn't find User for Mobile Number $mobileNumber");
      } else if (e.message == 'Too many elements') {
        print("Found duplicate Users for Mobile Number $mobileNumber");
      }
      return null;
    },
    test: (e) => e is StateError,
  );
}
```